# How can you run a python file from a VScode extension?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have been developing a VScode extension but haven't been able to run other python files and get the output data from these files. How do you run the python files from the extension?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think you'd be looking to call Python code from Node.js. An NPM package like `child_process` or `python-shell` should work, though I don't know if VS Code somehow locks up access to API's.

Answer (score -2):

You need to first setup your Python development environment. Specifically, this tutorial requires:

1. VS Code
2. VS Code Python extension
3. Python 3

From within VS Code, select a Python 3 interpreter by opening the Command Palette `(Ctrl+Shift+P)`, start typing the `Python: Select Interpreter` command to search.

You could refer to the [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_prerequisites) of vscode for more details.